# Not able to use GenyMotion 2.4.0 google Calendar

Tags: android, calendar, genymotion

I am building an android app which needs to create a calendar event. I use the following code for this:

```
    Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    calIntent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(calIntent);
```

The calendar even adding activity opens up but shows a dialog box-"Before you add a calendar event, you must add atleast one calendar event to your device and make a calendar visible"

So i add an account by entering my Google email id and password and i get the error:

> Cant safely connect to server.(java.security.cert.CertPathValidator
>   Exception: trust anchor for certificate path not found.)

Anyone else who got this issue? how to get this to work?

Comment: I think the emulator doesn't provide all features as the phone does. When I was developing an app, I used real phone for Google Maps, Videos etc and emulator for seeing layouts and other functionality of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the google play services in the genymotion virtual device in order to use your Google account for the calendar application.

To achive this purpose, follow this steps:

1. Download [ARM Translation Installer v1.1](http://www.mirrorcreator.com/files/0ZIO8PME/Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip_links)
2. Download the correct GApps for your Android version. [Here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=96039337900114811)  the last version for Android 5.1 or [here](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=23311191640114013) the 4.4 version.
3. Open your Genymotion VM and go to the Homescreen, drag&drop the Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip onto the Genymotion VM window. It should say "File transfer in progress", once it asks you to flash it click 'OK'. When finish restart VM.
4. Once you're on the Homescreen again drag&drop the gapps-5.1-2015-04-20-15-56-24.zip (or whatever version you got) onto your VM, and click 'OK' when asked. Once it finishes, again Reboot your VM.
5. Now you can add your Google account in settings. After that you can use google services for apps that you have installed like Calendar.

An image of my virtual device with google acount working:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tQdK.png

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not working, I could not add account, it gave couldn't open connection to server

Comment: @HirenPatel when you was trying to add an account, you had to specify  
`SECURITY TYPE: SSL/TLS (Accept all certificates)` instead of just a `SECURITY TYPE: SSL/TLS`.